# Replace fragment in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am trying to replace one of the fragments inside the ViewPager with another one.

The pager is composed by two pages: Fragment1 , Fragment2 
inside the fragment2, there is a button. When I click on the button, it will replace the current fragment, Fragment2, with Fragment3. For Fragment2, I want it to be destroyed and not exist anymore.

The implementation Code:

- Layout for activity_main:

  ```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
      app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  ```
- main_activity :

  ```
  private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
  private ViewPager mViewPager;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


      mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

      setupViewPager(mViewPager);

      TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
      tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       mSectionsPageAdapter.clearAll();              


  }

  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
      SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab 1");
      adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "Tab 2");
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
      viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  ```
- The Adapter:

  ```
  public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

      private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
      private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

      public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
          mFragmentList.add(fragment);
          mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
      }

      public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
          super(fm);
      }

      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
          return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          return mFragmentList.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return mFragmentList.size();
      }


  }
  ```
- Fragment2:

  ```
  public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {
      private static final String TAG = "Tab2Fragment";

      private Button btnTEST;

      @Nullable
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_fragment,container,false);
          btnTEST = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTEST2);

          btnTEST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });

          return view;
      }

  }
  ```

Update :

I tried to implement the method clearAll in the adapter  put I noticed the mFragmentList.size() return 0 why ?

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
 Log.d("tmz",mFragmentList.size()+" From  addFragment");  // return 1 & 2
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
    Log.d("tmz",mFragmentList.size()+"getCount "); // return 2 

}



public void clearAll(){
    Log.d("tmz",mFragmentList.size()+" From  addFragment"); // return 0 why ?
    for(int i=0; i<mFragmentList.size(); i++)
    fragMan.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentList.get(i)).commit();
    mFragmentList.clear();
    mFragmentList=new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling clearAll()?

Comment: Moreover, your addFragment() method needs to have notifyDataSetChanged() called at the end of it for the additions to take effect.

Comment: I made a change to my code, I put the clearAll() in oncreate() just to test the size of the mFragmentList, but still gave me a zero also after I put the notifyDataSetChanged() after the setup the adapter .

Comment: If you are calling it after the call to `setupViewPager()` then it should not return 0. Else you can put a breakpoint somewhere inside `addFragment()` and check at runtime, the values in the `mFragmentList`.

Comment: I did , with add Fragment() and getCount() the size will be 2 , but for clearAll() is zero, I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

remove from mFragmentList (and mFragmentTitleList) and add new, then call notifyDataSetChanged? also add to your `SectionsPageAdapter` for force redrawing `ViewPager` when notified.

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

not most efficient, but sufficient for your purposes. for adapter:

```
public void removeLastFragment() {
    if(mFragmentList.size()==0)
         return;
    mFragmentList.remove(mFragmentList.size()-1);
    mFragmentTitleList.remove(mFragmentTitleList.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick respond , but still not clear for me , where I can put the removeLastFragment inside the onClick Listener ,, and the getItemPosition inside the adapter . and what if I have 4 tabs and I want to replace the third fragment with a new one

Comment: also when I put removeLastFragment inside Adapter there is an error : " add (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in List cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: my mistake, there should be [`remove`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) instead of add, obviusly... If you will have more tabs then remove by index and add fragment on position by method [add(int index, E element)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)). use your brain, create your logic, I've provided you all needed methods

Comment: did you check the updated part , when I tried to access the mFragmentList size it gave me a zero why

Answer (score 0):

For zero it was because

```
SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

was repeated twice, and I solve my issue with use replace fragment inside the tab